# Python - Strip line at either one point or another in the same string

Tags: python

I want to save a phrase that´s between a start and a end point.

The start is `start = '->'`. The problem is that it can have two different end points (depending on which string I get) `end = ':\'` or `end1 ='[Channel]`.

So I'm trying to split the string at both ends `':\'` and `'[channel]'` in the same loop. I tried using `or, split, strip, striplines` and others, but nothing does the trick

How  my code looks now (not working)

```
        if line.startswith('->'):
                start = '-> '  # take string from
                end = ':\ ' #either end at this character
                end1 = '[Channel]' # or this character
                data.append(line[line.find(start) + 3:line.find(end or end1)].strip())
```

example on how the file with the strings looks

```
SEND TEST:
-> 3C 53 25 25 :\TCM_APP_33\MO\NO
-> 32 12 H2 3G [Channel]
-> 43 34 52 4B [Channel]
-> 4C 33 45 24 [Channel]
SEND TEST:
-> 35 32 5V 25 :\ KCM_APP_31\TEST\FIX
-> 3N 21 24 23 [Channel]
SEND TEST:
-> 12 3F 56 7D :\BCM_APP_31\TRY
-> 3N 21 24 23 [Channel]
```

Basically I want to extract the numbers

Comment: Can't you just split on the space ?

Comment: no i can´t because the file im searching in has many similar string (just took out some exempels from the file) ... so then i get every other string to, end and end1 are the only thing that´s special for this string @Mel

Comment: Then you need to show a more representative example of the data you're dealing with.

Comment: This is a replica of the data om sorting and i want to get the stings i need to get XX XX XX XX @Mel

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear in my question! The problem is fixed now  but thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple regex problem if your data is now how you have shown then you can solve this with regex pretty simply.

```
import re

numbers = re.compile("[\d|\w]{2}\s")
just_numbers = []
for line in data:
    just_numbers.append(" ".join([x.strip() for x in numbers.findall(line)]))

print(just_numbers)
```

Output

```
['12 3F 56 7D', '3C 53 25 25', '32 12 H2 3G']
```

In `[\d|\w]{2}\s` the `[\d|\w]` matches on characters that are either letters or numbers, so `0-9a-z-A-Z`. Then the `{2}` after it means I want strings that are exactly two characters matching the previous pattern (aka `[\d|\w]`. Finally the `\s` matches whitespace characters. So overall pattern matches all strings of the form `AA`, `1A`, `11` and so on. Note that there is a space after each of those.

Comment: Just for leaning purpose, what dose the [\d|\w]{2}\s illustrate and mean? is there som explikation for that

Comment: @fili I have added an explanation of what it does. It's regex though and you'll want to search up how that works for more general examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can split with space :

```
>>> s = "-> 4334524 [Channel]"
>>> data = s.split()
>>> data
[u'->', u'4334524', u'[Channel]']
>>> data[1]
u'4334524'
```

Edited:

```
>>> l = "-> 32 12 H2 3G [Channel]"
>>> str("".join(l.split()[1:5]))
'3212H23G'
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been more exakt with how the stings looked like

Comment: @fili : Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the help! really appreciated, but i got Nick Chapman´s exempel  to work

Comment: @fili : ok great

Answer (score 0):

try this. see the out put [here](http://ideone.com/NAQPZ8)

```
if line.startswith('->'):
    start = '-> '  
    end = ':\ '
    end1 = ' [Channel]' 
    x=line.strip(start)
    x=x.strip(end)
    x=x.strip(end1)
    data.append(x)
```

Comment: i hade som problems  getting this to work so tried Nick  Chapman´s  answer and that worker! Thank you anyway for answering,its really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
data="""
-> 123456 :\\
123 123
other data ...
-> 12 3F 56 7D :\\
-> 3C 53 25 25 :\\
-> 32 12 H2 3G [Channel]
-> 43 34 52 4B [Channel]
-> 4C 33 45 24 [Channel]
-> 35 32 5V 25 :\\
-> 3N 21 24 23 [Channel]
other data ...
123 123
-> hello [Channel]"""


numbers= [''.join(_.split()[1:-1]) for _ in data.split("\n") if _.startswith('->') and _.count(' ') == 5]
print (numbers)
```

**Output**

```
['123F567D', '3C532525', '3212H23G', '4334524B', '4C334524', '35325V25', '3N212423']
```

Split all lines, keep only lines beginning by `->` and with 5 spaces, split the spaces, don't keep the first and last result, merge the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The problem is fixed now, but thanks anyway!